# compare with any member of array using FILTER

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to get any AD object managed by users in specific office (NY for example).

Fastest way is to get all NY office users (100 users) and then get all AD objects managed by them via pipeline, because it's too slow to get all AD objects.

Its `ManagedBy` and `edsvaSecondaryOwners` properties. But how to match ANY member?

```
$NYC_users = Get-QADUser -Office 'New York' -SizeLimit 0 | select dn

filter FilterDN { 
    if (($_.managedby -in $NYC_users ) -or ($_.edsvaSecondaryOwners -in $NYC_users)) {
        $_
    }
}

Get-QADObject -SizeLimit 0 | FilterDN | select name,dn
```

The above code returns nothing.

How to properly compare `$_.value` with array?

Comment: `select dn` -> `select -Expand dn`. Also, is there a particular reason why you can't simply use `... | Where-Object {$_.managedby -in $NYC_users -or $_.edsvaSecondaryOwners -in $NYC_users} | ...`?

Comment: Thanks for expand, but how to deal if **$_.edsvaSecondaryOwners** is array? It could be so if more than 1 secondary owner..... (filter is faster)

Comment: Try `Compare-Object -Include -Exclude`.